# What is the consequence of defining subdomain name servers next to regular DNS Resource Records?

Tags: domain-name-system

I do not fully understand the working of subdomain-specific `NS` records and their implications for the working of DNS.

I regularly observe the use of `NS` records at the apex domain level, eg `example.nl`. The current layout of `A`/`AAAA`/`NS`/`SOA` records is:

```
example.nl.             0       IN      A       94.198.159.35
example.nl.             0       IN      AAAA    2a00:d78:0:712:94:198:159:35
example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ex2.sidnlabs.nl.
example.nl.             0       IN      NS      anytest1.sidnlabs.nl.
example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ex1.sidnlabs.nl.
example.nl.             0       IN      SOA     ex1.sidnlabs.nl. hostmaster.sidn.nl. 1081 14400 3600 604800 300
www.example.nl.         0       IN      A       94.198.159.35
www.example.nl.         0       IN      AAAA    2a00:d78:0:712:94:198:159:35
```

The name servers defined on the domain level also contain the resource records for the subdomain `www`. Now, in situation 1, we would add the same `NS` records for the `www` subdomain.

**Situation 1**:

```
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ex2.sidnlabs.nl.
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      anytest1.sidnlabs.nl.
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ex1.sidnlabs.nl.
```

In situation 2, we add different `NS` records for the `www` subdomain. Let's assume these nameservers hold different `A` and `AAAA` records for `www.example.nl`.

**Situation 2**:

```
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
```

My questions are:

1. Would Situation 1 change anything to the operation of DNS, in terms of which `NS` records are considered authoritative? Or would the `NS` records at the subdomain be ignored at all?
2. What is the outcome of quering `www.example.nl`, would it be the `A`/`AAAA` records located in the `NS` records of the domain name's nameserver, would it be the records located in the `www` subdomain's `NS` records, or would it be both?

Comment: using `dig +trace` should help you understand better how the resolution flow works.

the resolver will follow NS records until there are no additional pointers and then get the HOST record (A/AAAA/CNAME)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NS` records are used for delegations.

```
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ex2.sidnlabs.nl.
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      anytest1.sidnlabs.nl.
www.example.nl.             0       IN      NS      ex1.sidnlabs.nl.
```

This is rare but does/can happen with some CDN for example.

Normally you don't need that though, in the `example.nl` zone you just define `A`/`AAAA` or `CNAME` records for `www.example.nl` and you do not need any delegations.

The two situations you describe are the same. Operationally nothing is different, as long as the set of nameservers are properly configured of course.

> in terms of which NS records are considered authoritative?

There is no such question. The parent lists `NS` records, and the zone itself (the child) should list them as well, and both sets should match otherwise you are in a lame delegation case, and even if that can be considered only a warning and not an error:

- it is an error per core DNS specifications (RFC 1034 and 1035) even if immediately it may not create DNS problems
- it may introduce at least delays
- but does put the whole resolution in a fragile state insofar as any future change, even benign, can suddenly make everything break.

So in short, you should fix any lame delegation situation immediately. It is a sign of poor maintenance on the zone.

> What is the outcome of quering [www.example.nl](http://www.example.nl)

Clients follow delegations. If you have `NS` records in a given zone, pointing elsewhere, you shouldn't have, in the same zone, any other records below this cutpoint (but you may need glues, aka `A`/`AAAA` records, if the new nameservers are themselves in-bailiwick)

Also, and maybe unfortunately, what is more important is not what is in any zonefile in fact, but how the nameserver replies for some queries, if it gives answers or referrals (delegations). So it is hard to argue with just a dummy zonefile, better to see with real examples. You can use `dig +trace` as Jacob said, or use online troubleshooting tools like DNSviz that will graphically show you the delegations aka cut points, which are very important for proper DNSSEC operations.